# Spring Reactive Stack with Spring for Apache Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-kafka, project-reactor

In a few words:
I'm trying to decide between using the *default* Spring for Apache Kafka stack, [KafkaTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplate.html) or the pair, [ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/reactive/ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate.html) and [ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/reactive/ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate.html) for my Reactor based application.

Some more context:

In the company I work we're developing a high-disponibility application aiming to publish a set of requests directly to a Kafka Broker. Since this is an API centric application expecting to receive a few millions of requests per week, we decided to go with a stack based on the Project Reactor with Spring WebFlux and Kotlin.

After doing some digging I've discovered that the Spring for Apache Kafka has a simple wrapper designed around the [Reactor Kafka implementation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/api/#:%7E:text=Reactor%20Kafka%20is%20a%20reactive,pressure%20and%20very%20low%20overheads.), but this wrapper lacks a lot of the functionalities present in the *default* KafkaTemplate mentioned before, things like:  A Metrics Binder out of the box (for prometheus integration), associated [factories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.html), extensive documentation, Auto configuration, etc.

I'm trying to understand what I'm really giving up when using the *default* implementation in favor of the Reactive one. Am I giving up back pressure functionality? Am I sacrificing the Reactive Stack present in my application? Will this be a toll in the future? Does anyone has some experience in working with a Reactive Stack alongside a non-reactive solution?

I have, also, a few concerns regarding the DLT flow facilitated in the *default* implementation, things like the [SeekToCurrentErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.html) strategy

Comment: If your kafka message listeners need to do IO work (saving to database, making http calls), you can probably get higher throughput of processing messages with the reactive kafka, with fewer required threads.  Though the extra throughput and a bit more memory requirement may be worth it for the simplicity and Spring support of the regular Kafka template.  I am using it in a Spring WebFlux application without issues, as its processing happens in the kafka listener threads that are separate from the reactive http processing event loops.

Comment: Hi Martin OConnor, I am facing the same challenges currently. What have you decided to go with back then? Conscious some time has passed, and a reply would be much appreciated.

Comment: I was facing the same issue a few months ago and I've ended up following Michael's advice. Turns out, as he said, it doesn't really matter, the message itself is running in an exclusive thread. With VirtualThreads, tho, there's a possibility of reusing those threads!